# unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP. Xamarin warning

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I got this error while i **try to run my app on my Mobile**.
The app **run good on the Emulator** without warnings and errors.

I try to change my Google Play Services version to 24.2.1
but not help.

VS2015, My mobile Xiaomi Mi5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1>JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY\_GROUP in xamarin.android after adding xamari.support.v4 and xamarin.support.v7.AppC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42511741/1javac-warning-unknown-enum-constant-scope-library-group-in-xamarin-android)

Comment: I saw this question. But, its not happend to me while i adding the v4 & v7 support, its happend when i try to run the app on my mobile.

Answer (score 1):

If you add this warning after upgrading to Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2612. The [fix](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/727#issuecomment-1538487696) is simply to install Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation 1.6.0.4.